# DICOM Encoding Hierarchy ISO IR 100 vs ISO 2022 IR 87

Tags: encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, xml-serialization, dicom

I have a `DataContractSerializer` which uses an `XMLWriter`. By default the encoding for this is UTF8. I am working with DICOM data here. I serialize some header attributes from DICOM file. There is a patient with name in Japanese characters.

If the encoding for my input data in attribute`SpecialCharacterSet` `(0008,0005)` is set to ISO IR 100 then my serializer throws an exception. However, if I create the input data with ISO 2022 IR 87 then it serializes the data.

I would like to know whether ISO 2022 IR is a subset of UTF8 and ISO IR 100 is not?

Should I blindly create `XMLWriter` with `Unicode` encoding?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per DICOM current standard: [PS 3.5-2015c 6.1 Support of Character Repertoires](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part05/chapter_6.html#sect_6.1). We have:

> The ISO 10646-1, 10646-2, and their associated supplements and
>   extensions correspond to the Unicode version 3.2 character set. **The
>   ISO IR 192 corresponds to the use of the UTF-8 encoding for this
>   character set.**

And it is described further down that `ISO/IEC 2022:1994` is a **multi-byte** encoding (so definitely not UTF-8).